# Object oriented JS

Tags: javascript

Why it doesn't work? When I'm trying to call example.example() I'm getting TypeError: example.example is not a function.

```
var example = class {
constructor(){
    this.example = false;
}

id(){
    this.example = !this.example;
    return this.example;
}
};
```

Comment: This is not a good place for class expressions. Why not `class Example` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I'm trying to call example.example() I'm getting TypeError:
>   example.example is not a function.

`example` is a reference to an anonymous class, and **its constructor can only be invoked with `new`**

You need to call it as

```
var a = new example();
a.example; //false
```

**Demo**

```js
var example = class {
  constructor() {
    this.example = false;
  }

  id() {
    this.example = !this.example;
    return this.example;
  }
};
var a = new example()

console.log(a.example);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created class so you need to make an object of this.It should work by calling like this.

```js
var example = class {
constructor(){
    this.example = false;
}

id(){
    this.example = !this.example;
    return this.example;
}
};

console.log((new example()).id());
var obj = new example();
console.log(obj.id());
```